# Bluetooth earphones Jabra Rox Wireless not recognized under Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, android, bluetooth, headphones

I would like to connect my bluetooth (4.0) earphones (Jabra Rox Wireless) with my Lenovo X1 Carbon laptop running Ubuntu 14.04. If I activate bluetooth, set it to visible and start pairing mode on the earphones, no device is found. Is there any software I can install or how can I figure out what is missing? The earphones pair immediately with my Android phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the steps involved to discover and pair a bluetooth headset:

### Case new device never seen to the computer before

1. Hardware enable Bluetooth or plug in your Bluetooth dongle
2. Enable Bluetooth from the Bluetooth indicator (which had appeared on the top panel)
3. Put the headset in pairiging mode
4. Choose *Set Up New Device...*
   [image]
5. Choose your device from the list of new devices then press <kbd>Continue</kbd>
   *In the unusual case that your headset needs a PIN go to **PIN options...** first.*
   [image]
6. Wait until setup was completed:

   [image]

### Case re-paring a known device

In case we had already paired the device before we will not be able to see it on setting up a **New Device** as shown above. We then have to remove the device first before we can proceed:

1. Open *Bluetooth Settings*
2. Select the device in the list to remove with pressing on <kbd>-</kbd> button:

   [image]
3. Put your device in pairing mode
4. Press <kbd>+</kbd> to add a new device

   [image]
5. Proceed with 5. and 6. above.

**Note** Due to a yet incomplete Bluetooth integration to pulseaudio/sound-indicator we may have to run [pavucontrol](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol) [image: Install pavucontrol] once to be able to select the Bluetooth audio profile there. Switching profiles from A2DP to HFP may not yet work as expected.

Comment: Ah, so the only thing I did wrong was the order. The device has finally been found. Just as a note: I had to set it as output device in the system settings -> sound, and, additionally, choose 'Mode' as 'High Fidelity Playback (A2DP)' for it to work